# Is there a method to call an action after the button is released not as soon as the button is pressed?

Tags: android, button, kotlin, onclick

I want to call the following action after the button is released again:

```
 button.bringToFront()
```

My problem is that I only know how to trigger an action as soon as the button is clicked on. ->

```
button.setOnClickListener{
   button.bringToFront()

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Solution:

```
//Sound On/ Off
    soundon.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            /*when (event?.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ->  // On click

            }*/
            when (event?.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {soundoff.bringToFront(); println("on")}// Released

            }

            return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `onTouchListener`:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // RELEASED
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

In Kotlin try this

```
view.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            when (event?.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> //Do Something
            }

            return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you translate your answer to Kotlin, please?

Comment: How can I add multiple actions after the "->" like: println("abc"); view.bringToFront() ? @Anas Mehar

Comment: You can do like this "->{ println("abc"); view.bringToFront()}" for multiple expression

Comment: Look I updated my answer. The line println() is correctly executed when the user releases the button but the line soundoff.bringToFront() is executed on click. Why is that so?

Comment: if you using on touchlistener then way are you using onclicklisteners?

Comment: I don't understand the question.